# Like button Facebook for a specific news

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

after some research on the web I have not found what you do for me. I'm writing a site for a band with no cms and I have a news page where under each notice I would put the buttons I like, tweet and +1. Now as for the like button, I have not figured out how to tie the button to the individual news story and not the whole page of the site, so that when a visitor click "I like it", can only share the news and not the entire page neww.html
Thank you.

Comment: Each news article what you want to be able to be liked on its own must have its own individual URL under which it can be reached – because likes in the Open Graph work based on URLs, an individual URL is what identifies an individual Open Graph object.

Comment: so I have to build a page for every single news link and then the news from the page news.html with <a> </ a>?